# SessionID invalid in SOAP API but not affected in UI

Tags: api, soap-api, session

I have a session id (taken from an `Apex Class`) for a single sign on user which expires every 15 minutes of inactivity via SOAP API. But the Salesforce UI, if inactive for 15 minutes does not expire. It keeps on working with no session time out message and no logout page appears.

How can I maintain a session the UI does?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i found the answer, that particular salesforce console uses push notifications so when ever session id expires it automatically updates new one and stayed in UI.